# Error: no overload matches 'Log::Context.new' with type (Array(String) | Nil)

Tags: crystal-lang

I did update to crystal 0.35.1 via official docker image. Unfortunately, my project got compilation error somewhere inside crystal itself Error: no overload matches 'Log::Context.new' with type (Array(String) | Nil).

```
root@395e51d80ee6:/app# crystal spec --error-trace
In /usr/share/crystal/src/log/entry.cr:43:35

 43 | getter context : Metadata = Log.context.metadata
                                      ^------
Error: instantiating 'Log.class#context()'


In /usr/share/crystal/src/log/main.cr:56:18

 56 | Log::Context.new(Fiber.current.logging_context)
                   ^--
Error: no overload matches 'Log::Context.new' with type (Array(String) | Nil)

Overloads are:
 - Log::Context.new(metadata : Metadata)

Nil trace:

  /usr/share/crystal/src/log/main.cr:56

        Log::Context.new(Fiber.current.logging_context)
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  macro property (in expanded macro: macro_140471448844816:630):6

                def logging_context : Array(String) | ::Nil
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  macro property (in expanded macro: macro_140471448844816:630):7

                  @logging_context


  macro property (in expanded macro: macro_140471448844816:630):4

                @logging_context : Array(String) | ::Nil
```

My crystal version is

```
croot@395e51d80ee6:/app# crystal -v
Crystal 0.35.1 [5999ae29b] (2020-06-19)

LLVM: 8.0.0
Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 0):

My compilation was broken by `require "sidekiq"` (look like the shard is not maintained any more), I switched to `require "mosquito"`. IMO the Crystal compiler should show direct root course of the issue in the backtrace.